# How to use emacs tramp to edit remote python file?

Tags: python, emacs, tramp

I have installed the tramp on my emacs properly. I can use it to edit the remote txt files, however, once I create an *.py file on the remote host and edit it, after I input 2 letters, the whole emacs freeze, it doesn't respond. Could anyone give me some hints for this issus?

Comment: Tramp is part of Emacs. You would rarely need to install another version. Which version of Emacs (on which platform) are you running? Which version of Tramp are you using? Which Tramp method are you using?

Comment: And, what Python add-ons, and how are they configured? Sounds like one of them is incompatible with Tramp. If you let enough time pass, does Emacs recover, and do you get an error message?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out my mistake. Tramp seems incompatible with one of the python's auto-complete package, and I removed it. Then tramp works well.

Comment: EarthWorm: write that up as an answer to your question, and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. Tramp seems incompatible with one of the python's auto-complete package, and I removed it. Then tramp works well.